# Min & max values for initialize hash

Tags: ruby

```
class Airplane
  attr_reader :weight, :aircraft_type
  attr_accessor :speed, :altitude, :course

  def initialize(aircraft_type, options = {})
    @aircraft_type  = aircraft_type.to_s 
    @course = options[:course.to_s + "%"] || rand(1...360).to_s + "%" 
  end
```

How I can use minimum and maximum allowable values ​​for the hash in `initialize` from 1 to 360?

Example:

```
airplane1 = Airplane.new("Boeing 74", course: 200)
p radar1.airplanes
=> [#<Airplane:0x000000023dfc78 @aircraft_type="Boeing 74", @course="200%"]
```

But if I set to course value 370, airplane1 should not work

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What are the "allowable" values? What hash are you referring to? What do you expect the end value of said hash to be given certain inputs?

Comment: Okay, so you want to ensure that `options[:course]` is within a specified range of values? If it isn't though, what happens? ("Doesn't work" isn't very clear.)

Comment: yep, I want :course with a specified range of values, if it isn't - would be great to automatically insert the maximum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be refactored i'm sure but this is what i came up with

```
class Plane

  attr_reader :weight, :aircraft_type
  attr_accessor :speed, :altitude, :course

  def initialize(aircraft_type, options = {})
    @aircraft_type = aircraft_type.to_s 
    @course = options[:course] || random_course
    check_course  
  end

  def check_course
   if @course < 1 or @course > 360
      @course = 1
      puts "Invalid course. Set min"
     elsif @course > 360
      @course = 360
      puts "Invalid course. Set max"
     else
      @course = @course
     end
   end

   def random_course
    @course = rand(1..360)
   end

end
```

Comment: `rand` understanding a `Range` argument is a 1.9.3 thing that isn't in 1.9.2. PS: you're going to be doubling your `%` signs if you end up using a random course, no?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you don't want to let people pass in something like `{course: '9000%'}` for `options` and you want to error out if it's invalid. If that's the case, you can just test if it's in range:

```
def initialize(aircraft_type, options = {})
  @aircraft_type  = aircraft_type.to_s 
  allowed_range = 1...360
  passed_course = options[:course]
  @course = case passed_course
    when nil
      "#{rand allowed_range}%"
    when allowed_range
      "#{passed_course}%"
    else 
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid course: #{passed_course}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Which version of `rand` knows what to do with a Range? And raising an ArgumentError might be a better idea than a RuntimeError.

Comment: @muistooshort: 1.9.3 `rand` supports ranges. I'm pretty sure it's new in that version. Since the OP used it, I assumed it was a safe assumption to make that his Ruby was up-to-date. And you're right about the error type. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah, it is a 1.9.3 thing and I was using 1.9.2. That'll each me not to RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

`course` is an angle, isn't it? shouldn't it be `0...360` the valid range for it? and why the final "%"? and why work with a string instead of an integer?

Anyway, that's what I'd write:

```
@course = ((options[:course] || rand(360)) % 360).to_s + "%"
```